# Using apply() on different columns with different functions on each column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, series

I have a `DataFrame` which has columns name `age,salary`. There are some `NaN` values too. I want to fill those values using `Mean` and `Median`.

Original DataFrame

```
age salary
0   20.0    NaN
1   45.0    22323.0
2   NaN 598454.0
3   32.0    NaN
4   NaN 48454.0
```

**Fill missing `age` with the `mean()` and `salary` with `median()` of their respective columns using apply().**

I used

```
df['age','salary'].apply({'age':lambda row:row.fillna(row.mean()), 'salary':lambda row:row.fillna(row.median()) })
```

It is showing `Key error 'age','salary'` even after I use `axis=1`

**Ecpected Output**

```
    age salary
0   20.000000   48454.0
1   45.000000   22323.0
2   32.333333   598454.0
3   32.000000   48454.0
4   32.333333   48454.0
```

Can someone show me how to do it properly and what is happening in the background?

**Please tell if there are other ways too. I am learning Pandas from scratch**

Comment: hey Deshwal, can you post an example of your data and expected output?

Comment: @Datanovice Sure. I have updated. Please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about computing the missing values before running apply? That is, compute the mean of `age` and the median of `salary` then use (note the extra `[]` brackets needed to operate on multiple columns)

```
median_salary = df['salary'].median()
mean_age = df['age'].mean()

df[['age','salary']].apply({'age': lambda r: r.fillna(mean_age), 'salary': lambda r: r.fillna(median_salary)})
```

Also note that this does not affect the dataframe but instead creates a new one so if you want to update the columns use something like:

```
df[['age', 'salary']] = df[['age', 'salary']].apply(...)
```

Or, in your case where you just want to fill in missing values, the best solution is probably:

```
r.fillna({'age': mean_age, 'salary': median_salary}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks man! It was some useful knowledge that you just provided.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), the easiest way to do that you ask is to pass a dictionary as a `value` parameter:

> value : scalar, dict, Series, or DataFrame
>
> Value to use to fill holes (e.g. 0), alternately a dict/Series/DataFrame of values specifying which value to use for each
>   index (for a Series) or column (for a DataFrame). Values not in the
>   dict/Series/DataFrame will not be filled. This value cannot be a list.

in your case the code will be next:

```
df.fillna(value={'age': df.age.mean(), 'salary': df.salary.median()}, inplace=True)
```

and gives:

```
         age    salary
0  20.000000   48454.0
1  32.333333   22323.0
2  45.000000  598454.0
3  32.333333   48454.0
4  32.000000   48454.0
5  32.333333   48454.0
```